# How would I manipulate a string to display different parts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

I have a string in a dictionary that's in an array that I need to manipulate a bit. The string returns: `TEST-TEST-ABC_Dry_Cleaning-R12-01`.

Here's what I need to do with it:

- I need to pull out "ABC_Dry_Cleaning" and change it to "ABC Dry Cleaning" (no underscores)
- I need to delete "TEST-TEST-"
- I need to pull out "R12" and put that in a different string
- I need to add "01" on to the end of "ABC Dry Cleaning" (looks like "ABC Dry Cleaning (01)")

How would I do these general things? There is much more that needs to be done, but once I know the way to do these tasks I can change it around for the others as needed. NOTE: "ABC_Dry_Cleaning" could be just "Red_Cups" or "McDonalds_Bag" - basically, a count of characters won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on iOS4+, consider using a regular expression to match the segments that you're interested in retaining. Take a look at the [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

You can then use the matches to build up the final string.